# ¿Cuando se copia una clase no se llama al constructor?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo una prueba donde he creado una clase que imprime una frase en el constructor para saber cuando se está llamando al mismo.

```
class Example
{
public:
    int x;

    Example()
        : x(0)
    {
        std::cout << "Example created" << std::endl;
    }
    Example(int _x)
        : x(_x)
    {
        std::cout << "Example " << x << " created" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Después he creado otra clase que contiene también esta clase en sus parámetros.

```
class Entity
{
private:
    Example example;
public:
    Entity() 
        : example() {}
    Entity(int _x)
        : example(_x) {}
    const Example GetName() const
    {
        return example;
    }
};
```

La cosa es que he hecho que el getter no me devuelva la variable por referencia, por lo que se debería crear una copia de "example". Lo que me extraña es que cuando se crea la copia de "example" no se llama al constructor ya que que la consola no me imprime la frase que le he puesto. ¿Alguien sabe por qué al crear la copia no se llama al constructor?

Comment: Todos los clases tienen un constructor de copias. Si no lo defines, el compilador lo definirá automáticamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los objetos pueden construirse a base de otros. Cuando copias el `Example`, lo que se llama es al constructor por copia. (Copy Constructor, no se como se traduce correctamente)

Prueba especificarlo en tu código:

```cpp
class Example
{
public:
    int x;

    Example()
        : x(0)
    {
        std::cout << "Example created" << std::endl;
    }
    Example(int _x)
        : x(_x)
    {
        std::cout << "Example " << x << " created" << std::endl;
    }
    Example(const Example& e)
    {
        x = e.x;
        std::cout << "Example Copied" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Y esta es la salida que da:

```
Example 1 created
Example Copied
1
```